# K-th element of two sorted Arrays

Tags: arrays, sorting, optimization

Given two sorted arrays A and B of size M and N respectively and an element k. The task is to find the element that would be at the k’th position of the final sorted array.

Question is from GeeksforGeeks

This is the code i have written for the above question. I have just concatenated the given two arrays in to a third array and then sorted it. I have written in C language. I lack knowledge regarding how to write a code in an optimized way. Please help me out by letting me know how to optimize the code so that, it takes less execution time.

```
 for (i = 0; i <= n1 - 1; i++)
{
  scanf ("%d", &a[i]);
}
  for (i = 0; i <= n2 - 1; i++)
{
  scanf ("%d", &b[i]);
}
  for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
{
  c[i] = a[i];
}
  for (j = n1, i = 0; j <= z - 1 && i <= n2 - 1; j++, i++)
{
  c[j] = b[i];
}
  for (i = 0; i <= z - 1; i++)
{
  for (j = i + 1; j <= z - 1; j++)
    {
      if (c[i] > c[j])
    {
      temp = c[j];
      c[j] = c[i];
      c[i] = temp;
    }
    }
}
  printf ("%d", c[q]);
```

I have got the output, but the problem i am facing is..
Your program took more time than expected.Time Limit Exceeded
Expected Time Limit < 0.324sec
Hint : Please optimize your code and submit again.

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudocode of MergeSort, an algorithm for effective merging of two sorted arrays, which is worst-case optimal:

```
function void mergesort(S array; l,r integer) {
    if (l<r) then
    #Sort each
        ~50% of array
        m := (r-l)
        div 2;
        mergesort(S, l, l+m);
        mergesort(S, l+m+1, r);
        #merges two sorted lists
        merge( S, l, l+m ,r);
    else
        # Nothing to do, 1-element list
    end if;
}


function void merge(S array; l,m,r integer) {
    B: array[1..r-l+1];
    i := l;
    # Start of 1st list
    j := m+1;
    # Start of 2nd list
    k := 1;
    # Target list
    while (i<=m) and (j<=r) do
        if S[i]<=S[j] then
            B[k] := S[i]; # From 1st list
            i := i+1;
        else
            B[k] := S[j]; # From 2nd list
            j := j+1;
        end if;
        k := k+1;
    # Next target
    end while;
    if i>m then
    # What remained?
        copy S[j..r] to B[k..k+r-j];
    else
        copy S[i..m] to B[k..k+m-i];
    end if;
    # Back to original list
    copy B[1..r-l+1] to S[l..r];
}
```